# How much accuracy can I get with RF / acoustic triangulation?

Tags: signal-processing

Lets say I wanted to track an object locally in 3D space. This object could be transmitting at low power. I could have 3 or more receivers in the same room as an object. How much accuracy could I expect to get in practice?

Would my calculation be based just on received strength or would it make sense to do something such as send coded pulses in order to synchronize them. ie by determining the phase difference of the pulses relative to each receiver to improve accuracy. I guess this accuracy would be dependant on frequency?

Comment: Would suggest you read up on how the world wide GPS system works.  What you're proposing is sort of the inverse of this.

Comment: What accuracy you would get depends on the system and the surroundings. **But** the first challenge will be to get a working system. Power level detection is not a reliable detection method because of reflections of the signals. You can forget about RF because RF travels at the speed of light, synchronization will be a impossible. Only radar (transmit and receive from the same unit) can work at RF at such small distance.

Comment: You can get good accuracy. Here are some things to consider. Is the air temperature controlled or can it be measured? The speed of sound in a gas depends on the temperature of the gas. Are there air currents? Air currents will degrade the accuracy. Is signal processing available somewhere? If the three signals can be fed to a PC or DSP  as timestamped data sequences, signal processing can be used to provide a pretty accurate position. This would work best if the ultrasound was modulated in some fashion and that the modulation did not repeat to often. Maybe once per second or something.

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering using this in a room, I suggest you avoid RF and go acoustic. RF travels about 11 inches each nanosecond, so you would need to be able to synchronize time measurements down to nanoseconds (and the cables to the sensors would be an ingredient in the measurement).

Sound, on the other hand, travels about 13 inches per millisecond. You can get millimeter accuracy with a simple microcontroller with timers. Also, cable lengths will become insignificant.

Put a piezo transducer on the object that you wish to track. A short ultrasonic burst a few times each second would be all you need. Something like a 40 kHz tone, lasting 1 millisecond, repeated every 50 millisecond (that will cover a 50 foot sphere). Put a bandpass filter with discriminator for each sensor, and then trigger timers at the leading edge of each burst. The time delta between the received pulses would allow you to triangulate the 3D position (for 3D space, you would need a minimum of 4 sensors).

Comment: Speed of sound in a gas is a function of gas temperature. It may be advisable to somehow control for temperature, either by measuring temperature or by having a a sensor/receiver pair at known distance for calibration purposes.

Comment: Hi @mkeith - You're right, the temperature affects the delay. But it affects all delays equally, and can be cancelled out when you apply the trigonometry (using the law of similar triangles), assuming the sensors are properly positioned (opposite sides of the room, for instance). You also need a minimum of four sensors for 3D, arranged to create four non-parallel planes.

Comment: I am not sure if that is true. Or, rather, the ability to correct for speed of sound errors may be very position dependent and doing it adds a bit of complexity to the solution.

Comment: It really isn't complex at all. The measured delays aren't treated as distances at all, but are treated as the legs of triangles. Each triangle's shape would be the same, regardless of the speed of the medium. The triangles' shapes are then used in conjunction with the known distances between the sensors to compute the position. The speed of the medium never needs to be considered.

Comment: I will take your word for it. Too lazy to think it through right now.